# Align this div wtih links under this element

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

I've a created a page which has video and links of the video to play and the link element with div class part-links here and i want to align that under the video element with display inline effect just like this:

[image]

If any one could solve this problem I would be very thankful and it would be great

here's the code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(130deg, rgb(230, 124, 71), rgb(197, 166, 62));
  height: 900px;
}

.hdlg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.hdlg>img {
  width: 22vw;
  height: 29vh;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.slg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.brd {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid rgb(98, 96, 96);
  ;
  width: 39%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 31%;
  right: 0%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.cont {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(221, 207, 173, 0.605);
  width: 95%;
  height: 87%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 4px solid white;
  border-right: 4px solid white;
  border-left: 4px solid white;
  border-top: 4px solid white;
}

#vid-player {
  width: 65%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.prtd {
  display: inline;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #7ba758;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgb(104, 99, 25);
  color: black;
  height: 12vh;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 17px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .hdlg>img {
    width: 48vw;
    height: 25vh;
  }
  .slg {
    font-size: 27px;
  }
  #thmb {
    width: 60vw;
    height: 36vh;
  }
  .box {
    width: 62vw;
    height: 48vh;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .box:hover {
    height: 51vh;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .cont {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  .brd {
    width: 45%;
    left: 28%;
    right: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Vid</title>
</head>

<body>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="hdlg">
      <img src="log0.png">
    </div>
    <span class="slg"><h2>logo</h2></span>
    <span class="brd"> </span>
    <div class="cont">
      <video id="vid-player" controls>
           <source src="part1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
           Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
       </video>
      <div class="prtd">
        <a class="alnk" href="#" data-src="part3.mp4">Part 4</a>
        <a class="alnk" href="#" data-src="part.mp4">Part 1</a>
        <a class="alnk" href="#" data-src="part.mp4">Part 2</a>
        <a class="alnk" href="#" data-src="part3.mp4">Part 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired result by adding `flex-direction: column` to the `cont` class. That will change the direction in which flex items are rendered. You can also remove the uncessary `width` and `height` attributes from `prtd` class if you want them to be on the same row like in the screenshot.

Edit:

Changed the `height` of `prtd` class to be `65%` (same as video) and changed display to `flex` to allow for `justify-content: space-around;`

Edit 2:

I recommend you read up on how flex-box works, it will really help you implement your designs better and with less css jargon. I have found [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to be useful in the past.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(130deg, rgb(230, 124, 71), rgb(197, 166, 62));
  height: 900px;
}

.hdlg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.hdlg>img {
  width: 22vw;
  height: 29vh;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.slg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.brd {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid rgb(98, 96, 96);
  width: 39%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 31%;
  right: 0%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* change flex direction */
  background-color: rgba(221, 207, 173, 0.605);
  width: 95%;
  height: 87%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 4px solid white;
  border-right: 4px solid white;
  border-left: 4px solid white;
  border-top: 4px solid white;
}

#vid-player {
  width: 65%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.prtd {
  display: flex; /* changed display to flex */
  width: 65%; /* changed width to be the same as video */
  justify-content: space-around; /* seperating items */
  /* remove height here */
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.alnk {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #7ba758;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgb(104, 99, 25);
  color: black;
  height: 12vh;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 17px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .hdlg>img {
    width: 48vw;
    height: 25vh;
  }
  .slg {
    font-size: 27px;
  }
  #thmb {
    width: 60vw;
    height: 36vh;
  }
  .box {
    width: 62vw;
    height: 48vh;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .box:hover {
    height: 51vh;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .cont {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  .brd {
    width: 45%;
    left: 28%;
    right: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Vid</title>
</head>

<body>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="hdlg">
      <img src="log0.png">
    </div>
    <span class="slg"><h2>logo</h2></span>
    <span class="brd"> </span>
    <div class="cont">
      <video id="vid-player" controls>
           <source src="part1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
           Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
       </video>
      <div class="prtd">
        <a class="alnk" href="#" data-src="part3.mp4">Part 4</a>
        <a class="alnk" href="#" data-src="part.mp4">Part 1</a>
        <a class="alnk" href="#" data-src="part.mp4">Part 2</a>
        <a class="alnk" href="#" data-src="part3.mp4">Part 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: he does not try to center the buttons (in terms of flexbox). Using `text-align: center` is the wrong way to go. What he needs instead is `align-items: space-around;`. And then push the buttons/anchors out of the container.

Comment: @tacoshy do you mean `align-content` maybe? `align-items` doesn't have that property. And yes, `text-align: center` doesn't accomplish anything. The spacing between the links should definitely be done through flexbox, I agree.

Comment: this does not seperate each of the buttons

Comment: @TheCreativemindsandgamer edited my answer, let me know if this is more in-line with what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a flex-direction: column in your .cont. This will make them the video and your buttons align vertically.

```
.cont{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
```

If you want your buttons to align horizontally you need to remove width: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.php

To make them seperate just remove the background color from .prtd and add it to .alnk

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(130deg, rgb(230, 124, 71), rgb(197, 166, 62));
  height: 900px;
}

.hdlg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.alnk{
  background-color: #7ba758;
}

.hdlg>img {
  width: 22vw;
  height: 29vh;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.slg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.brd {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid rgb(98, 96, 96);
  ;
  width: 39%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 31%;
  right: 0%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* change flex direction */
  background-color: rgba(221, 207, 173, 0.605);
  width: 95%;
  height: 87%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 4px solid white;
  border-right: 4px solid white;
  border-left: 4px solid white;
  border-top: 4px solid white;
}

#vid-player {
  width: 65%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.prtd {
  display: inline;
  /* remove width and height here */
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgb(104, 99, 25);
  color: black;
  height: 12vh;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 17px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .hdlg>img {
    width: 48vw;
    height: 25vh;
  }
  .slg {
    font-size: 27px;
  }
  #thmb {
    width: 60vw;
    height: 36vh;
  }
  .box {
    width: 62vw;
    height: 48vh;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .box:hover {
    height: 51vh;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .cont {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  .brd {
    width: 45%;
    left: 28%;
    right: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Vid</title>
</head>

<body>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="hdlg">
      <img src="log0.png">
    </div>
    <span class="slg"><h2>logo</h2></span>
    <span class="brd"> </span>
    <div class="cont">
      <video id="vid-player" controls>
           <source src="part1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
           Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
       </video>
      <div class="prtd">
        <a class="alnk" href="#" data-src="part3.mp4">Part 4</a>
        <a class="alnk" href="#" data-src="part.mp4">Part 1</a>
        <a class="alnk" href="#" data-src="part.mp4">Part 2</a>
        <a class="alnk" href="#" data-src="part3.mp4">Part 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: justify-content will center along the main-axis which in this case will be the vertical axis. It has no effect as the height is calculated to fit-content. According to the picture, he does not try to center the buttons (in terms of flexbox).

Comment: @tacoshy you are right I removed it

Comment: use `align-items: space-around;` that centers the buttons as he intends according to the picture.

Comment: i also want to seperate each

Comment: @TheCreativemindsandgamer I recreated MissSkooters code snippet, if you want to make the buttons different edit .alnk